# Is there an un-adjacent selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css, selector

I'm building a website where I want to hover on certain images and have them display other divs.

I found this JSfiddle which worked well. http://jsfiddle.net/ZSZQK/

```
<div id="image"><img src="image.png"/></div>

<div id="hover">Test message</div>

#hover {
    display: none;
}

#image:hover + #hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Only I need to split my divs up, meaning they are no longer adjacent, like this. http://jsfiddle.net/Z2H66/

```
<div class="first-container">
    <div class="image"><img src="image.png"/></div>
</div>    

<div class="second-container">
    <div class="hover">Test message</div>
</div>

.hover {
    display: none;
}

.image:hover + .hover {
    display: block;
}
```

What tools are at my disposal that are able to do what I'm asking?

Also note I changed my code to classes rather than ids, but that doesn't stop it working. My code doesn't work because the div `hover` and `image` are not adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the modified version of your JSFiddle which uses Javascript and jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/scorchio/ZSZQK/288/

jQuery will let you handle hover events like this easily, the key is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide on start
    $("#hover").hide();

    // Handle mouse over for image
    $("#image").hover(function() {
            // This one is when the mouse enters
            $("#hover").show(); 
        },
        function() {
            // ...and when it hides.
            $("#hover").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for that. I'm using wordpress for this site so had to do a bit of research and tweaking to get it to load in a noConflict  wrapper, but your code works great.

Comment: @pappy Nice to hear that you even get the noConflict part running, thumbs up! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `~` is a little less strict, but that's not going to help you here :(

With pure css, I think this is the best you can do:

```
.hover {
    display: none;
}

.first-container:hover ~ .second-container .hover {
    display: block;
}
```

See [this post about css parent selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) (not implemented), and [this link from one of the answers that has a javascript shim for it](https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector).

By the way, the `~` is adjacent, but not immediately adjacent, unlike the `+`.

Comment: While I went for the above jQuery answer, I do appreciate yours, and will look into the tilda selector for future use. Thank you.